# How can I give filename to the StringIO and send it with Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, file-management

I'm trying to dynamically create and send some files with Telegram Bot using Python. So I'm collecting the data in StringIO and successfully send it with Telegram Bot and as expected I get a document with name 'document' in the other side with whole data... But I want to give a name to it... I know that Telegram Bot API doesn't allow manually setting filenames, so I want to do that before sending... But as I see I can't set filename to the StringIO... So any good alternatives? Do I need to use temporary files anyway?

```py
buffer = StringIO()
call_command('dumpdata', 'main', stdout=buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
worker.bot.send_document(worker.administrator_page, buffer, caption='Data of {}'.format(datetime.now().isoformat()), reply_to_message_id=worker.message['message_id'])
```

I expect to get a file with correct filename in the other end (as a Telegram User).

Comment: I think you will need to use a temporary file if you want a filename. [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) might fit the bill.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at it! And if you know any way to simulate opened file with StringIO or any other tool, it would be great to hear that :)

Comment: Sorry, offhand I don't. Perhaps you could use some sort of ramdisk software...

Comment: Interesting technology! I'll check that out, but I'm not sure if that will help me solve the problem... If you know any exact way how to solve the problem with ramdisk that would be great!